# Make a dataframe from a variable

Tags: python, function, dataframe, variables

I have written a function that grabs the latest file from a folder, using `get_latest_file`. It looks something like this:

```py
def get_latest_file(path, *paths):
```

This variable called `path` is simply the path to where the file is located, and `*paths` is the actual file itself. I have set:

```py
file = get_latest_file(path, '*000.xls')
```

I want to make `file` into a dataframe. How can I do this?

I tried using `pd.DataFrame(file)` and also tried to do `pd.read_excel`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import glob
import os

def get_latest_file(path, *paths):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, *paths)
    list_of_files = glob.iglob(fullpath)
    if not list_of_files: 
            return None
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key = os.path.getctime)
    _, filename = os.path.split(latest_file)
    return filename

path = r'\\filepath'

file = get_latest_file(path, '*000.xls')
print (file)

df = pd.DataFrame(file)
print(df)
```

**note**

`filepath` in the code above is not the actual path and `000.xls` is not the actual file name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "I tried using pd.dataframe(file) also tried to do pd.read_excel", what was the result? if you got an error, please include the error traceback in your question. If the results were not what you wanted, please describe how it was different from your expected result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, put it may have to do that `*paths` in your function definition is **not** interpreted as a wildcard (which I think is your intention), but to pass a variable number of positional arguments. See e.g. https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Note that `*args` is just convention, it's the asterisk that does the magic. So in your case `*paths` is interpreted as a variable number of arguments which can be accessed in the functions body with `paths[0]`, `paths[1]` etc.

Hope this helps.